# Making backlight brightness persistent across reboots

Tags: display

I have two X200 Thinkpads.  They both have the rather annoying problem
that, unless the display backlight is set to its maximal value, it emits
an unbearable noise.  The odd thing is that one of them boots with the
max. value and the other does not.  It is also impossible to set the
second computer's display to the max. brightness value by using the
brightness-up button (it will only reach 779942 of 846600).  I have to

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Now the sound goes away but only until the next reboot.  Is there
anything I can do to make the brightness value persistent across reboots?

PS.  I understand that I can run a script on startup, but *something* is
making my first comptuer different and I would like to know what.  I
have tried this using the exact same OS (the same live USB), and both
computers have the same BIOS version (from 2012; 7.22?) and settings.
The difference is also there in the BIOS setup, before loading any OS.

(PS II.  I might add that the problem does not exist in Windows, even
with the screen dimmed.)

Comment: My guess is that you can set the display brightness in the bios setup. Config -> Display -> Brightness -> High/Normal (I don't have an X200 right now, but that's the option on an X61). The buzzing sound is most likely a dying inverter. Your displays are non-led, right?

Comment: @Freddy, my only option in config/display is 'boot display device', which is set to 'thinkpad lcd'.  so do you think this will go away if i replace the inverter?

Comment: @Toothrot Damn, the brightness option is already gone like on all newer Thinkpads. Yes, if it's not the inverter, then it's an issue with the CCFL (usually getting darker until it sometimes fails). But an inverter swap is not so complicated and they're cheap nowadays (ebay). See [here](https://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?t=106813) and [here](https://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=127321).